# When using ngFor don't introduce line breaks

Tags: css, angular

I have ngFor as follows:

```
<div class="image-holder" *ngFor="let image of datasource">
    <img src="{{image.url}}" height="150" />
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.image-holder
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**This is what I have:**
[image]

**This is what I want:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `float: left;`?

Comment: Use a `span` instead.

Comment: @echonax Yes, I have tried it. But no chage in output

Comment: @Vishal sorry the `float: left;` needs to be added to your img element. `<img src="{{image.url}}" height="150" style="float:left;" />`

Comment: @DanielCooke Yes, that works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better would be to use `display: flex` on a wrapper element, and not use the ancient `float`:

**html**

```
<div class="images-wrapper">
    <div class="image-holder" *ngFor="let image of datasource">
        <img [src]="image.url">
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.images-wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-holder {
   padding: 2px; /*for white border around images*/
   height: 120px;
}

.image-holder img {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Check here for a cute working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrao3x5g/), no angular included, because this is mainly a css/html issue.

Comment: Yes it works well but I also want that images should be justified, so that spaces between images should be adjusted automatically.

Comment: I added `justify-content: space-between` to `wrapper` and it works fine. Thank you very much for great answer

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be fixed just with CSS:

```
.image-holder
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-holder img {
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

And you can keep the same html but removing the height attribute in the `img`:

```
<div class="image-holder" *ngFor="let image of datasource">
    <img src="{{image.url}}" />
</div>
```

**Quick tip:**

For adjusting the `CSS` styles you can inspect the element in Chrome or Firefox and modify the css rules in the browser's panel until you get the desired output. Then you go to your code and copy those same rules and see how it goes.

Is quicker than modifying code all the time and spamming F5. :D

**Update 1 - Flexbox solution:**

```
container { 
  padding: .5vw;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}

container div { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  height: 150px; 
  margin: .5vw; 
}

container div img { 
  height: 100%;
}
```

And the html:

```
<container>
    <div *ngFor="let image of datasource">
         <img src="{{image.url}}" />
    </div>
<container>
```

Comment: That does not work. I mean the output is same. Look at the comment from @DanielCooke that works.

Comment: @Vishal I updated my answer with a full Flexbox solution. Hope it suits you or helps you whatsoever. Good luck man!